# Tomcat 8 JDBC and Oracle PDB Connection problem

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

I have a Java 8 Web Application that is running on Tomcat 8. I have configured a JDBC connection in the server.xml file to connect to an Oracle 12c Container database.

```
<Resource accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" maxIdle="10" maxTotal="25" maxWaitMillis="10000" name="jdbc/LOCALDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:admin/admin123@localhost:1521/DBSVC"/>
```

For my application I have used both ojdbc6 and ojdbc7. When I start Tomcat and attempt to connect to the database I get the following error:

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

Despite the error SQLPlus and SQL Developer can connect to the service and SID so the connection definitely works. This article (https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-connecting-to-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1) suggests that you may see this error when using JDBC and to use the following property in the listener configuration file.

```
USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_listener=on
```

This, unfortunately, does not work for me and it only changes the error from the above to the following:

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Output for the lsnrctl status shows:

```
[oracle@bcc0fa014b84 ~]$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 22-OCT-2020 11:50:45

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                22-OCT-2020 11:49:29
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 1 min. 16 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/bcc0fa014b84/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=bcc0fa014b84)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/opt/oracle/admin/DBX/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "DBX" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "DBX", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "DBXXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "DBX", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "aeb6317d78400953e053020011ac120e" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "DBX", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "DBX", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "dbsvc" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "DBX", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "DBX", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Services on the database as follows:

```
[oracle@bcc0fa014b84 ~]$ lsnrctl services

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 22-OCT-2020 11:54:31

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
Services Summary...
Service "DBX" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "DBX", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:1 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "DBXXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "DBX", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: bcc0fa014b84, pid: 89>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=bcc0fa014b84)(PORT=36517))
Service "aeb6317d78400953e053020011ac120e" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "DBX", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:1 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
  Instance "DBX", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: bcc0fa014b84, pid: 89>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=bcc0fa014b84)(PORT=36517))
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "dbsvc" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "DBX", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:1 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
  Instance "DBX", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: bcc0fa014b84, pid: 89>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=bcc0fa014b84)(PORT=36517))
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

As it stands, I am at a loss as to why Tomcat can not connect to my Oracle Database. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this may be? Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the output of "lsnrctl status"? What service name is created after your change to USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_listener?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for getting back to me. Updated post with requested output but it shows listeners available to connect with services ready from what I understand of the output. I'm unsure what service was created as a result of adding USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_listener i wasn't aware it created a new one.

Comment: Have you tried "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" in the JDBC URL?